# How Cast to unknow class

Tags: java, class, casting

I have a class:

```
public class Example {
    public String name; 
}
```

but this class does not have to be called Example may be different(like Example2, AnotherExample I don't know how), the problem is that I do not know how to be called.

In another class I have a method which take as parameter a list of objects.
My Example class:

```
public class ObjectClass{
    public List<Object> doSomething(List<Object> objects) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < objects.size();i++) {
            Class<?> c = objects.get(i).getClass();
            System.out.println("class name " + c.getCanonicalName());// i get name my class
            System.out.println(((Example) objects.get(i)).name);
        }
    }
}
```

When I change the cast Example to another class like this `System.out.println(((c) objects.get(i)).name);`
it doesn't work.

My class can call itself differently then cast to Example will not work.
Generally speaking I want get value of name, while not knowing how the class is named. But I select which class with a field name(or by having an annotation).
Edit: is one problem, it is my homework and i can't change class Example, and i can't change method doSomething.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look specifically after a field name, you can also iterate over all fields via reflection and access the right one.

```
public List<Object> doSomething(List<Object> objects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        Class<?> c = objects.get(i).getClass();
        for (Field field : c.getFields()) {
            if ("name".equals(field.getName())) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("class name " + c.getCanonicalName());// i get name my class
                    System.out.println(field.get(objects.get(i)));
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of polymorphism.  Here is what you can do:

```
interface Named
{
    String getName();
}

public class Example implements Named
{
    public String name; 

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}

public class AnotherExample implements Named
{
    public String name; 

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

then you can do this:

```
        System.out.println(((Named) objects.get(i)).getName());
```

then of course I would also recommend that you do the following:

```
public List<Named> doSomething(List<Named> objects) {
```

so that then you can do this:

```
        System.out.println(objects.get(i).getName());
```

Edit after clarification:

If you cannot add your own interface, then try something like this:

```
Object foo = objects.get(i);
if( foo instanceof Example )
{
    Example example = (Example)foo;
    ...do something with example...
}
else if( foo instanceof AnotherExample )
{
    AnotherExample anotherExample = (AnotherExample)foo;
    ...do something with anotherExample...
}
else
{
    assert false; //I do not know what class this is.
}
```

Comment: thanks for try help, but i add edit to my post, since I can't change class Example and i can't add my own interface, only what i can is write code into class ObjectClass( i can't chcange Declaration method doSomethnig)

Comment: I think that it is still not what I mean, because my homowerk is that I do not know how a class is called. My teacher called class Example like he want , i don't know name of class.

Comment: well, if this is homework, then this is almost certainly about polymorphism, so your solution lies in the first part of my answer. You have misunderstood something about the assignment: either you are in fact allowed to alter `Example` and add an interface to it, or you are supposed to create your own `Example` class, in which case of course you can add whatever interface you want to it.